# How do I pipe commands into Inkscape --shell in windows cmd?

Tags: windows, batch-file, inkscape

I am trying to build a script to batch convert a bunch of file using inkscapes `--shell` mode. The simple question is: how do I pipe a string of commands to shell mode for execution (without using the interactive shell)?

This wont work im cmd:

```
"C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin\inkscape.com" --shell "file-open:C:\Users\***\file.svg; export-type:pdf; export-do;"

** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:22596): WARNING **: 16:56:30.053: Fonts dir 'C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\inkscape\fonts' does not exist and will be ignored.
ink_file_open: '' cannot be opened!
InkscapeApplication::document_open: Failed to open: file-open:C:\Users\***\file.svg; export-type:pdf; export-do;
ConcreteInkscapeApplication::on_open: failed to create document!
```

Unfortunately, I can't use Powershell.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you just use the command line options? `inkscape --export-type="pdf" file.svg`.  Just so you are aware, you can't write to the root of the C: drive without elevated permissions.

Comment: [Search for pipe and redirect with the batch-file tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5Dpipe+redirect). You have options, such as redirecting a file, string literals or environment variables, to stdin.

Comment: @Squashman Commandline Options use one instance per conversion and are therefore slow. Not really an option for many files. Also, Inkscape often freezes (maybe [this bug?](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1659172) no idea how to reproduce, though).

Comment: @jwdonahue since cmd has no real pipe, the workarounds wont work if I cant get this simple example to work with one string. (I tried...)

Comment: @MoritzH. that is what FOR loops are used for.  You could start multiple instance of Inkscape to run at the same time.

Comment: @MoritzH, does inkscape.com not use stdin in shell mode?  If it does, then cmd's "unreal" pipes should work just fine. Put all the commands you want to send it in a file and pipe the file into it.